# Java IRC, processing login command correctly

Tags: java, irc

For school I have to create a java irc client without using libraries (pircbot for example). I have created a bot called "skynet". This bot handles all the commands I send to it.

But for a login function I need the command to be processed with the senders username and not with the BOTS (skynet)

```
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))
    else if (line.contains("!LOGIN")) //!LOGIN <username> <password>
    {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        String user = parts[4];
        String pass = parts[5];
        String inpUser = user;
        String inpPass = pass; 

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Leroy/Documents/users.txt"));
        {
            String UserPass; //user#pass
            while ((UserPass = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String Pass = UserPass.split("#")[1];
                String User = UserPass.split("#")[0];
                if (inpUser.equals(User) && inpPass.equals(Pass)) 
                {
                    System.out.print("Login succesfull: " + "\r\n"); //word onder naam van user geprint

                    writer.write("NICK " + user + "\r\n"); //dit moet verstuurd worden onder naam van de user NIET DE BOT
                    writer.write("PASS " + pass + "\r\n");
                    writer.flush();
```

This gives the following console output:

```
:skynet!~skynetbot@53533763.cm-6-4a.dynamic.ziggo.nl NICK :boa
```

Here it changes/logs the bots name in the specified username (BOA). But I need it to change/login the username of the user who send the command.

For example, if I join a #channel with the username: leroy
and i send !LOGIN BOA CONSTRICTOR i want to change the users nick to the given login username/nick.
Output needs to be:

```
leroy!leroy@53533763.cm-6-4a.dynamic.ziggo.nl NICK :boa
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of your `users.txt` file?

Comment: With !register <username> <password> i write the username and password to a line in the txt file seperated by a #.    example:   USERNAME#PASSWORD

Comment: I suggest that you put a breakpoint on the line `if (inpUser.equals(User) && inpPass.equals(Pass))` and that you see in which case it evaluates to true and writes your output. If your input string is `!LOGIN <username> <password>` and you split it on a whitespace, it looks wrong to get the 4th and 5th value from that split as the entered username and password. Then again, the snippet doesn't seem complete so I could be wrong as well.

Comment: Let me confirm - you want to write a bot (which logs in to an IRC server as a standard client), which you want to be able to forcibly change the nickname of another client?

Comment: Yes that is what i would like to do.

Comment: Yeah... that's not possible as a client connection - it'd would be a massive security hole in the protocol. You could write your bot as a network service, which would require you to implement the server protocol, and would require you to reconfigure the IRC server to recognise your bot as a new IRC server. Bear in mind that the server protocol is subtly different to the client protocol.